# Segmentation Fault 11 in C caused by larger operation numbers

Tags: c, macos, memory, segmentation-fault, fft

I have known that when encountered with `segmentation fault 11`,  it means the program has attempted to access an area of memory that it is not allowed to access.

Here I am trying to calculate a Fourier transform, using the following code.

It works well when `nPoints = 2^15` (or of course with less points) , however it corrupts when I further increase the points to `2^16`. I am wondering, is that caused by occupying too much memory? But I did not notice too much memory occupation during the operation. And although it use recursion, it transforms in-place. I thought it would occupy not so much memory. Then, where's the problem?

Thanks in advance

PS: one thing I forgot to say is, the result above was on Max OS (8G memory).

When I running the code on Windows (16G memory), it corrupts when `nPoints = 2^14`. So it makes me confused whether it's caused by the memory allocation, as the Windows PC has a larger memory (but it's really hard to say, because the two operation systems utilize different memory strategy).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <string.h>

// in place FFT with O(n) memory usage

long double PI;
typedef long double complex cplx;

void _fft(cplx buf[], cplx out[], int n, int step)
{
  if (step < n) {
    _fft(out, buf, n, step * 2);
    _fft(out + step, buf + step, n, step * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * step) {
      cplx t = exp(-I * PI * i / n) * out[i + step];
      buf[i / 2]     = out[i] + t;
      buf[(i + n)/2] = out[i] - t;
    }
  }
}

void fft(cplx buf[], int n)
{
  cplx out[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) out[i] = buf[i];

  _fft(buf, out, n, 1);
}


int main()
{
  const int nPoints = pow(2, 15);
  PI = atan2(1.0l, 1) * 4;

  double tau = 0.1;
  double tSpan = 12.5;
  long double dt = tSpan / (nPoints-1);
  long double T[nPoints];
  cplx At[nPoints];

  for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; ++i)
  {
    T[i] = dt * (i - nPoints / 2);
    At[i] = exp( - T[i]*T[i] / (2*tau*tau));
  }

    fft(At, nPoints);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably the arrays are to large to be allocated on stack. Make them global or `static`.

Comment: don't use `pow(2, 15);` for integers use `1<<15`

Comment: `out[i + step]`: `out` has `n` size, and `i` varies up to `n`. That's a problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure `PI` should be provided by your math library...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for your reply. But I am not sure why `pow(2, 15` is not suitable? And what does `1<<15` mean?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree. But do you know the limit of the array that C can allocate? Because I still think `2^15` is not a number to large

Comment: @RoyLiao Depends on the system you are working on. It might be not *the* problem.

Comment: If you want to do some FFT stuff, but don't know the available operators of C language, you could get a hard time.... Check your C text book for bitwise shift operators.

Comment: the posted code is using recursion.  Each recursion consumes more of the stack.  In most systems (especially in Windows) there is a limit to how much stack is available.

Comment: `1<<15` shifts 1 by 15 positions, it's like 2 elevated to the power of 15.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So `1<<15` is one kind of bitwise operation right?

Comment: @user3629249 I know that each recursion consumes much stack. But I do not know how to improve. Have you any suggestion?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for your suggestion. I am working on it.

Comment: exactly. Look bit shifting.

Comment: suggest moving all the array declarations to 'file global' memory rather than on the stack.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That is okay because `i` is incremented by `2*step`, and `2*step` is always a factor of `n`. Therefore, `i` never takes a value that is larger than `n - 2*step`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot allocate very large arrays in the stack. The default stack size on macOS is 8 MiB. The size of your `cplx` type is 32 bytes, so an array of 2<sup>16</sup> `cplx` elements is 2 MiB, and you have two of them (one in `main` and one in `fft`), so that is 4 MiB. That fits on the stack, but, at that size, the program runs to completion when I try it. At 2<sup>17</sup>, it fails, which makes sense because then the program has two arrays taking 8 MiB on stack. The proper way to allocate such large arrays is to include `<stdlib.h>` and use `cmplx *At = malloc(nPoints * sizeof *At);` followed by `if (!At) { /* Print some error message about being unable to allocate memory and terminate the program. */ }`. You should do that for `At`, `T`, and `out`. Also, when you are done with each array, you should free it, as with `free(At);`.
2. To calculate an integer power of two, use the integer operation `1 << power`, not the floating-point operation `pow(2, 16)`. We have designed `pow` well on macOS, but, on other systems, it may return approximations even when exact results are possible. An approximate result may be slightly less than the exact integer value, so converting it to an integer truncates to the wrong result. If it may be a power of two larger than suitable for an `int`, then use `(type) 1 << power`, where `type` is a suitably large integer type.

Comment: I think you have just got the exact right solution here. Thanks so much! Both suggestions are practical. vielen danke

Answer (score -1):

the following, instrumented, code clearly shows that the OPs code repeatedly updates the same locations in the `out[]` array and actually does not update most of the locations in that array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <assert.h>



// in place FFT with O(n) memory usage
#define N_POINTS  (1<<15)

double T[N_POINTS];
double At[N_POINTS];
double PI;


// prototypes
void _fft(double buf[], double out[], int step);
void fft( void );


int main( void )
{
    PI = 3.14159;

    double tau = 0.1;
    double tSpan = 12.5;
    double dt = tSpan / (N_POINTS-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < N_POINTS; ++i)
    {
        T[i]  = dt * (i - (N_POINTS / 2));
        At[i] = exp( - T[i]*T[i] / (2*tau*tau));
    }

    fft();

    return 0;
}


void fft()
{
    double out[ N_POINTS ];

    for (int i = 0; i < N_POINTS; i++)
        out[i] = At[i];

    _fft(At, out, 1);
}


void _fft(double buf[], double out[], int step)
{
    printf( "step: %d\n", step );

    if (step < N_POINTS)
    {
        _fft(out, buf, step * 2);
        _fft(out + step, buf + step, step * 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < N_POINTS; i += 2 * step)
        {
            double t = exp(-I * PI * i / N_POINTS) * out[i + step];
            buf[i / 2]     = out[i] + t;
            buf[(i + N_POINTS)/2] = out[i] - t;
            printf( "index: %d buf update: %d, %d\n", i, i/2, (i+N_POINTS)/2 );
        }
    }
}
```

Suggest running via (where `untitled1` is the name of the executable and on linux)

```
./untitled1 > out.txt
less out.txt
```

the out.txt file is 8630880 bytes

An examination of that file shows the lack of coverage and shows that any one entry is NOT the sum of the prior two entries, so I suspect this is not a valid Fourier transform,

Comment: You have printed the indices within the array passed to `_fft` at each step. However, in one of the calls, the array passed to `_fft` is offset by `step`, so the index within the passed array is offset from the index within the original array. The combination of steps used throughout the recursion results in all elements of the array being used, as designed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil,  The value of `step` is doubled each recursion.  I.E. 1, 2, 4,8,16, 32, 64. 128, 256, 512,...  The recursions do not handle the increasing size of `step`, So not all the array is updated.

Comment: After changing the arrays to be allocated by `malloc`, I ran the source code. All elements of the array were updated. The first call to `_fft` separates the array into `out+0` and `out+1` with a step size of 2, so one processes all the even elements and the other all the odd elements. The first of those arrays is passed to `_fft` recursively, which separates it into `out+0` and `out+2` with a step size of 4. The second is passed and separated into `out+1` and `out+3` with a step size of 4. This continues recursively, so that some element that is 1101 in binary is processed in…

Comment: … the second call (bit 1) of the second call (bit 1) of the first call (bit 0) of the second call (bit 1) of `_fft`.